# Trigonometrical equation

Tags: trigonometry

I have some problem with finding $\cos2x$ if $\cos^6x-\cos6x=1$

I replace the $\cos6x= \cos^23x-\sin^23x$ but I'am not sure it's a good way to figure it out.

Comment: This seems like an exercise that explores the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Trigonometric_definition

Comment: More to the point, you can write $\cos 6x$ as a $6$th-degree polynomial in the variable $\cos x$.  Look here at $T_6(x)$.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Examples

Answer (score 1):

Your exercise is equivalent to finding $2u^2 - 1$, for $u$ a solution to the polynomial equation
$$
u^6 - \left( 32u^6 - 48u^4 + 18u^2 - 1 \right) = 1.
$$
This boils down to finding roots of the polynomial
$$
31u^6 - 48u^4 + 18u^2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\displaystyle\cos2x=y,\cos6x=4y^3-3y$ as $\displaystyle\cos3A=4\cos^3A-3\cos A$

Again, $\displaystyle\cos^6x=\frac{(2\cos^2x)^3}8=\frac{(1+y)^3}8$

So, the equation becomes $$\frac{(1+y)^3}8-(4y^3-3y)=1$$

$$\iff -31y^3+3y^2+27y-7=0$$

Comment: @Greor, clearly one value of $y$ is $-1\implies \cos2x=-1=\cos\pi\implies 2x=(2n+1)\pi$ where $n$ is any integer. The rest two values can be easily deduced by solving the following quadratic equation : $$\frac{-31y^3+3y^2+27y-7}{y+1}=0$$